# Shape function for quarter point element from degenerate quadrilateral

Tags: finite-element, interpolation

I want an element as the one shown following.

[image]
[image]

Nodes 6 and 8 are in the quarter position.

Whether eight node quadrilateral element or six node triangle function can be used directly？

If not, how to build a new shape function？

Answer (score 2):

You could find the shape functions proposing a quadratic function of
the form

$$N_i = a_0 + a_1 r + a_2 s + a_3 rs + a_4 r^2 + a_5 s^2\, ,$$

and enforcing the following condition

$$N_i(r_j, s_j) = \delta_{ij}\, ,$$

that is, 1 for each node and 0 for the others.

I am using as reference element a triangle with vertices $(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)$, and assuming that the quarter-position nodes are on the vertical and horizontal edges. Thus, you end up with the following list of points (in "order")

$$(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1/4, 0), (1/2, 1/2), (0, 1/4)\, .$$

You then solve the 6 systems of equations to find the coefficients and get the following

\begin{align}
&N_{0}{\left(r,s \right)} = 4 r^{2} + 8 r s - 5 r + 4 s^{2} - 5 s + 1\, ,\\
&N_{1}{\left(r,s \right)} = \frac{4 r^{2}}{3} - \frac{2 r s}{3} - \frac{r}{3}\, ,\\
&N_{2}{\left(r,s \right)} = - \frac{2 r s}{3} + \frac{4 s^{2}}{3} - \frac{s}{3}\, ,\\
&N_{3}{\left(r,s \right)} = - \frac{16 r^{2}}{3} - \frac{16 r s}{3} + \frac{16 r}{3}\, ,\\
&N_{4}{\left(r,s \right)} = 4 r s\, ,\\
&N_{5}{\left(r,s \right)} = - \frac{16 r s}{3} - \frac{16 s^{2}}{3} + \frac{16 s}{3}\, .
\end{align}

All these calculations are easier done with a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system). In my case, I used [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/). The following code solves the problem

````py
import sympy as sym

# sym.init_printing()

a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = sym.symbols("a0:6")
r, s = sym.symbols("r s")


N = a0 + a1*r + a2*s + a3*r*s + a4*r**2 + a5*s**2

pts = [[0, 0], [1, 0] , [0, 1], [sym.S(1)/4, 0],
     [sym.S(1)/2, sym.S(1)/2], [0, sym.S(1)/4]]

shape_funs = []
for j in range(6):
    eqs = []
    for k in range(6):
        if j == k:
            rhs = 1
        else:
            rhs = 0 
        eq = N.subs({r: pts[k][0], s: pts[k][1]})
        eqs.append(sym.Eq(eq, rhs))
    sol = sym.solve(eqs, [a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5])
    shape_funs.append(N.subs(sol))
```
````

Comment: I use this shape function in Mathematica to compare with the result in ABAQUS and find it is not accurate

Comment: @sgzslg, that's not the question that you asked.